# Simplest way to construct a matrix its elements are defined by known functions

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to construct a n*m matrix, such that:
1- its first element is given by:

```
c0 = 1 - 4/\[Pi] (1 - 10^-4)*
NIntegrate[
 1/u^2*Sin[u/2]^2/(1 + 10^-7*I*Sqrt[u^2 - 0.006^2]), {u, 
  0, \[Infinity]}];
```

2- The rest elements of the first row are given by:

```
f[n_] := 4/\[Pi] (1 - 10^-4)*(-1)^(n + 1)*NIntegrate[
1/(1 + 10^-7*I*Sqrt[u^2 - 0.006^2])*Sin[u/2]^2/(
 u^2 - 4*n^2*\[Pi]^2), {u, 0, \[Infinity]}];
```

3- Diagonal elements -except first element; say x[[1,1]] that is defined in 1- are given by:

```
g[m_] := 1 - 8/\[Pi] (1 - 10^-4)*NIntegrate[
 u^2/(1 + 10^-7*I*Sqrt[u^2 - 0.006^2]) Sin[
    u/2]^2/(u^2 - 4*m^2*\[Pi]^2)^2, {u, 0, \[Infinity]}];
```

4- The rest elements X[[n,m]] are given  by:

```
fnm[n_, m_] := 8/\[Pi] (1 - 10^-4)*(-1)^(n + m + 1)*NIntegrate[
u^2/(1 + 10^-7*I*Sqrt[u^2 - 0.006^2]) Sin[
   u/2]^2/((u^2 - 4*n^2*\[Pi]^2)*(u^2 - 4*m^2*\[Pi]^2)), {u, 
 0, \[Infinity]}];
```

My question is could you please tell me what is the simplest way with mathematica I can use to construct arbitrary n*m  X matrix  may be  100*100 matrix for example.

Answer (score 2):

One of many possible ways (and certainly not an optimal one):

```
X = ConstantArray[0., {n, m}];
X[[1, 2 ;;]] = Array[f, {m - 1}, 2];
X[[2 ;;]] = Array[fnm, {n - 1, m}, {2, 1}];
LinearAlgebra`SetMatrixDiagonal[X, Join[{c0}, Array[g, {Min[n, m] - 1}, 2]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fn[x_, y_] := Which[
  x == 1 && y == 1, c0,
  x == 1, f[y],
  x == y, g[y],
  True, fnm[x, y]
  ]
result=Array[fn, {100,100}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to redefine your function so that it is consistently named, and then use the Outer product. With`f[n,m]` as defined, let `f[1,m]` be your current `f[m]`, let `f[m,m]` be your `g[m]`, and set `f[1,1]=c0`. Then you can define the matrix as:

```
Outer[f, Range[n], Range[m]]
```

For an easy visualizable example:

```
Clear[f]; f[1, m_] := f[m]; f[m_, m_] := g[m]; f[1, 1] = c0;
n = 4; m = 6; Outer[f, Range[n], Range[m]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: All of you, Thank you very much. I tried all the three suggested ways. In fact I found that the bill s's way is the simplest one!!! Many thanks bill s!

Comment: The usual thing to do with answers you like is to upvote them. Then wait a few days, and if no better answers appear, to accept them.

Comment: Thank you bill for your advise.