# Perform same operation along dimension of an array

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, procedural-programming, table

If I want to add the $2\times 2$ matrix `b` along the first dimension of `a` that has $n\times 2\times 2$ dimensions I can do this by `For` or `Table` that work very slowly. Is there a faster way?

```
n = 10^7;
a = ConstantArray[0, {n, 2, 2}];
b = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
Timing[Table[a[[i, ;;]] += b, {i, 1, n}]][[1]]
(* 21.1406 *)
```

**Edit**

Here is a comparison for the running time of the given solutions:

````
n = 10^7;
b = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
a = ConstantArray[0, {n, 2, 2}];

Timing[Table[a[[i, ;;]] += b, {i, 1, n}]][[1]]
(* 18.4 seconds *)

Timing[a = Flatten[BlockMap[# + {b} &, a, {1, 2, 2}], 3]][[1]]
(* 5.0 seconds *)

Timing[a = Table[a[[i]] + b, {i, 1, n}]][[1]]
(* 2.2 seconds *)

Timing[a += ConstantArray[b, n]][[1]]
(* 1.2 seconds *)

Timing[a = Map[(# + b &), a]][[1]]
(* 0.91 seconds *)

Timing[a = Transpose[Transpose[a, {3, 1, 2}] + b, {2, 3, 1}]][[1]]
(* 0.14 seconds *)
```
````

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99171/1871  There should be more.

Comment: For me the easiest solution is `Map[(# + b &), a]` but it is 2 times slower than the method provided by @xzczd.

Comment: +1 I like the ordering of the methods according to their timing.

Comment: @userrandrand and granular bastard, I add a more advanced solution, have a look :) .

Comment: OP, I think you should run all of them with ``b = Developer`ToPackedArray[{{1,2},{3,4}}]`` if it is a question about performance tuning. And instead of `Timing`, consider using the more accurate  `AbsoluteTiming` or `RepeatedTiming`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `b=Partition[Range[4], 2]`. Then b is automatically packed as can be checked with Developer`PackedArrayQ.

Comment: Another solution is `Query[All, (# + b) &]@a` but it is practically equivalent to map both in the idea and the speed.

Comment: Numpy (python package) takes about 0.1 seconds and the method provided by @xzcd takes about the same amount of time. To compare with python `ExternalEvaluate[
  "Python", {"import numpy as np", "from timeit import default_timer as timer", "start = timer()", "a=np.zeros((10**7,2,2))",  "b=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])", "c=a+b",  "end = timer()",  "end - start"}] // Last`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
AbsoluteTiming[rst = Table[a[[i, ;;]] + b, {i, 1, n}];][[1]]
(* 14.8407 *)

rst2 = Transpose[Transpose[a, {3, 1, 2}] + b, {2, 3, 1}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.366587 *)

rst == rst2
(* True *)
```

A more advanced solution, based on the knowledge obtained from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270431/1871):

```
Block[{a, b},
 cf = 
    FunctionCompile[
     Function[{Typed[a, "PackedArray"["Integer64", 3]], 
               Typed[b, "PackedArray"["Integer64", 2]]}, 
      Module[{carr = Array`GetData@a, carr2 = Array`GetData@b, 
              len = Length@Flatten@a, step = Length@Flatten@b},
       Parallel`ParallelDo[
         Do[ToRawPointer[carr, i + j, carr[[i + j]] + carr2[[j]]], 
            {j, 0, step - 1}], 
                           {i, 0, len - 1, step}];]]]; // AbsoluteTiming]
(* {2.70636, Null} *)

cf[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.124746 *)

rst == a
(* True *)
```

Up to *v13.1*, the compilation is still slow, but we only need to do it once.

Notice pointer is used in this solution, so `a` is modified. Even if you store it in another variable e.g. `aForTest = a;` and then `cf[aForTest, b]`, `a` will still be modified.

Comment: Faster but not very readable. And the Transpose might demand additional memory.

Comment: @granularbastard Indeed, this syntax of `Transpose` is advanced, I suggest reading [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14810/1871) to learn more about it. (It's about `Flatten`, but the underlying idea is quite similar. ) And trust me, if extremely high performance is the goal to achieve, readability is always lost to some degree :) .

Comment: I actually disagree about readability. I think @xzczd's answer is highly readable. I don't use this syntax often enough to be able to be able to immediately "see" the detaila, but it's very easy to "see" the intention: restructure to take advantage of listability of addition, do the addition, return to original structure. Very nice.

Comment: For what it's worth, to me, the most readable of all would be to use Threaded: `a + Threaded[b]`. But it provides no performance improvement (which kind of surprised me).

Comment: BlockMap gives some performance improvement (about a factor of 3), but not as nice as the Transpose strategy. `Flatten[BlockMap[# + {b} &, a, {1, 2, 2}], 3]`. Some might find that more readable.

Comment: Interesting... Since the `;;` was superfluous, tried timing the OP's original without it, and performance improved by a factor of about 6. Also, the `+=` was much slower than just constructing a new array. So, to be specific, the original could have been sped up with these minor changes: `Table[a[[i]] + b, {i, 1, n}]`.

Comment: To defend OP's point of view given the discussion above, I agree that solutions that use this form of `Transpose` or solutions that use `Transpose` twice are difficult to read for me.

Comment: Yeah, this is why I think that advice about making your code "readable" or "understandable" or "keep it simple, stupid" is just uesless advice. Readable depends on context and on the individual's familiarity with the particular jargon or techniques being used. I think that `Map[(# + b &), a]` probably is the most readable for a majority of non-neophyte Mathematica users.

Comment: @lericr I would say that readability can be be given a precise definition in terms of the time required for a hypothetical perfect student to understand the code with no prior knowledge of the language and perfect documentation. In particular the lowest number of high level function calls and parameters. Along that criteria I think your `Threaded` solution is by far the most readable and should be an answer here as it's not that popular.

Comment: ok i take back what I said. I tried the thread method and it crashed my mathematica (:

Comment: @lericr I add a more advanced solution, have a look :) .

Comment: Numpy (python package) takes about 0.1 seconds and the method provided by here takes about the same amount of time. To compare with python `ExternalEvaluate[   "Python", {"import numpy as np", "from timeit import default_timer as timer", "start = timer()", "a=np.zeros((10**7,2,2))",  "b=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])", "c=a+b",  "end = timer()",  "end - start"}] // Last`

Comment: It seems to me that the function compiles a lot faster when preceded by Clear[a,b]. Why  would that be ?

Comment: @userrandrand Wow, this is surprising! Thx for pointing out, edited. This looks like a bug to me, given `FunctionCompile` is still EXPERIMENTAL.

Comment: (+1) I won't be surprised if you go lower and fiddle around the LLVM IR emitted by `FunctionCompile` and see some other performance improvements. :)

Answer (score 6):

This

```
a + ConstantArray[b,n]
```

takes 7.5 seconds. However with `b` packed

```
a + ConstantArray[b // Developer`ToPackedArray ,n]
```

it takes only about 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Nice. For those that are unfamiliar with Developer`ToPackedArray or packed arrays the answers for this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/86543) could be interesting.

Comment: Alternatively, in this specific case, one could use `b=Partition[Range[4], 2]`. Then b is automatically packed as can be checked with Developer`PackedArrayQ